# How to allow NuxtJS(app) webpage to open in an iFrame and stored on S3 served via CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-s3, iframe, amazon-cloudfront, nuxtjs

I am working on one website which has the feature like widget, there are few pages that I need to allow to open in iFrame. I have created one separate `index.html` file which has one iframe and that iframe's src is URL of the one page of the NuxtJS app. When I run this `index.html` file(open in browser) I am getting an error

```
Refused to display 'https://example.com/widgets/new/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
```

When I run the project locally(localhost) and use the local URL `https://localhost:3000/widgets/new/` of the page as iframe's src then it works. but not in production.

I looked around the internet but couldn't find any related solution to try.

Is there any option or config in NuxtJS which I can use to set the x-frame option to allow(true) on certain routes or pages?

I am using the Amazon S3 Bucket to store the project and using the Amazon CloudFront to serve the website.

Comment: Are you proxying requests to NuxtJS app with nginx? Can you show that `location` block from your nginx config?

Comment: Yes, I'm proxying requests to the NuxtJS app with Nginx. I haven't done any extra steps with Nginx, can you share the configuration need to be done Nginx for what I want to achieve? @IvanShatsky

Comment: Are you sure you don't have anything related to `X-Frame-Options` header in your nginx config? It would be better if you include your server block within your question.

Comment: Apologies for not including full details:

Here is the important detail that I missed that I am using the Amazon S3 Bucket to store the project and using the Amazon CloudFront to serve the website.

Comment: It looks like it is CloudFront who adds this `X-Frame-Options` header. I don't have any experience with it, found [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/adding-http-security-headers-using-lambdaedge-and-amazon-cloudfront/) article mentioning HTTP security headers control with AWS. You'd better change your question title regarding CloudFront and add the `aws-cloudfront` tag to have more chances that someone who has a better knowledge of this subject answers it.